# iptables Accept Routing Requests

Tags: iptables, routing

I have the following setup:

Server A: Which has connected clients via openvpn. Clients are given a specific ip. (Example: 10.253.0.10)

Server B: which has connected modems via openvpn. modems are given a specific ip range (Example: 172.16.167.0/24)

Server A has a route to Server B. So all requests going to 172.16.167.0/24 are routed to Server B. This works.

Server A has an iptables rule to allow the above. This also works:

```
-A FORWARD -s 10.253.0.10/32 -d 172.16.167.0/24 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

The question is now, which IPTables settings do I need to set on Server B? If I completely turn off iptables on Server B, the client is able to access the targeted network.

Comment: What does `iptables -vnL` on Server B show in the first place? Probably you are not allowing the required traffic in the INPUT chain. For completeness sake, also show `iptables -vnL -t nat`, `iptables -vnL -t mangle`, `iptables -vnL -t raw`.

Comment: -t nat, -t mangle and -t raw all display no rules. So I am guessing I am missing something there I assume.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of all four commands I asked for.

Comment: Won't you just need the same or similar rule on Server B?